# Bullet points inside div

Tags: css

I want to have bullet points inside a div to which I assigned the class "standard". I am overriding another class that shows a background for list items. Nothing happens:

```
div.standard ul li {
display:list-item !Important;
list-style-type: disc !Important;    
}
```

The page is the following:
http://mw.theseolounge.co.uk/index.php/marsden-m-300.html
and the list of items is under Key Features.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you mean Product Features?

Comment: I don't see any div having a class "standard" on your page

Answer (score 0):

You are applying the styling to list item `li` directly whereas it should be applied to the actual list `ul` or `ol` itself. Try the following css which applies the styling directly to the list:

```
div.standard ul{
  display:list-item !Important;
  list-style-type: disc !Important;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `list-style-type` in the `ul`, not the `li`. And I think you can get rid of `display: list-item`.